Issue with Authentication for Twitter API v2 Endpoints - Error 403 Forbidden
I'm experiencing trouble with authentication while running a script to collect data from Twitter using the Twitter API v2 endpoints. The error message indicates a 403 Forbidden error.

If anyone has any advice or a solution,please don't hesitate to share them with me. Your help is greatly appreciated.
I'm using keys and tokens from a Twitter developer app attached to a project created via the developer portal. Even though I checked that my credentials are correct, the error persists.

You haven't mentioned which endpoint are you trying to use to collect data. If it is the recent search endpoint or Tweet lookup endpoint you need appropriate level of API access (atleast Basic API access is necessary)
Free API plans are only able to POST or Create Tweets
